# Can't Compile Crypto++ Library for IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, crypto++

I'm trying to build a static cryptopp library for ios. I'm basing my steps from these sites:
http://cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_(Command_Line)#Xcode_Project 
https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-5.6.2-ios 
https://www.cryptopp.com/

1.) I downloaded the latest cryptopp version 5.6.3 
2.) I downloaded noloader's cryptopp-5.6.2-ios becasue it has updated:

```
setenv-ios.sh - i had to edit this to search for sdk 9.2
GNUmakefile
config.h
build-for-ios.sh
```

3.) I copied the four files to my cryptopp 5.6.3 directory and replaced GNUmakefile and config.h

4.) I checked out IOS_Command_Line instruction to invoke setenv-ios.sh first.

5.) Then, as noloader said, run build-for-ios.sh.

However, i'm getting this error:
[image]

Has anyone successfully built the library using the latest ios SDK and cryptopp version? If so, can you please point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: I can't see what the error is because the print is too small in the picture. Could you provide the text of the error? Also, You should be using `GNUmakefile-cross`, not `GNUmakefile`. Finally, use the latest Crypto++ sources as described at [GitHub and Git](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GitHub_and_Git). It has a couple of mobile fixes since 5.6.3 released.

Comment: We recently added a message to [direct you to the next step after running `setenv-*.sh`](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/a6090c64edfc51d9d573398d4b266b2718d09546). I'm kicking myself in my ass-end because I should have realized it was needed a long time ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation was not correct under [IOS (Command Line) | Build the Library](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_%28Command_Line%29#Build_the_Library). After setting the environment with `setenv-ios.sh`, you should use `GNUmakefile-cross`:

```
$ make -f GNUmakefile-cross static dynamic cryptest.exe
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -fPIC -pipe -Wall -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor  -arch armv7 -isysroot 
/Applications/Xcode-5_1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
-stdlib=libc++ -c cryptlib.cpp
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -fPIC -pipe -Wall -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor  -arch armv7 -isysroot 
/Applications/Xcode-5_1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
-stdlib=libc++ -c cpu.cpp
clang++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -Os -fPIC -pipe -Wall -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor  -arch armv7 -isysroot 
/Applications/Xcode-5_1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
-stdlib=libc++ -c 3way.cpp
...
```

I *thought* we updated the iOS procedures when we updated the Android procedures. I'm not sure what went wrong the documentation updates.

---

We checked in the scripts for `setenv-ios.sh`, `setenv-android.sh` and `setenv-embedded.sh` in March 2016. `GNUmakefile-cross` was already in the library. Also see [Commit a78b9dfa0840f92f, Added iOS environment and test script](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/a78b9dfa0840f92fed9d61f1a4a3b5ce403e55fd) and [Commit 22d6374ce7151ad0, Added Android and embedded environment and test script](http://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/22d6374ce7151ad030a3194edf2cb37a30318820).

All you should need to do now is the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git
cd cryptopp

. ./setenv-ios.sh
make -f GNUmakefile-cross static dynamic cryptest.exe
...
```

The new/updated files will be available in the ZIP at the next Crypto++ release, which will be either 5.6.4 or 5.7.0.

Comment: Can I ask what would I use cryptest.exe for?

Comment: @RjCristy - The primary use for me is running test vectors and validation suites. But stepping back earlier in the process, it ensures the library is linkable.

Comment: Why would it be named "exe"? It's confusing, since we're talking Xcode (and Mac, which we know doesn't execute exe)? Sorry I'm quite new to c++

Comment: @RjCristy - `cryptest.exe` has the EXE extension primarily for two reasons. First is historical. Its been that way for about 25 years. Second is users and training. We have one set of procedures that differ as little as possible on all platforms. If instructions are complicated, then users get confused, they ask questions and they file bug reports.